# MacBook Pro extremely slow and with a sluggish Internet connection after macOS Catalina update

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, macos-catalina

I am using a MacBook Pro (Late 2012) with the following specs:

- **Processor speed**: 2.9 GHz
- **Memory**: 8GB
- **Available disk space**: 160 GB (main partition) and 359 GB (on a second partition).

I recently (3 days ago) update Apple suggested update of macOS Catalina. After the update and about 24 hours later my computer became very slow to work with any applications I tried to launch. In addition, I noticed that my home internet connection is properly connected (both through Wi-Fi and Ethernet) but it's confusingly sluggish.

Before and just after the update my internet used to be fairly fast. For example for the update, it took only about 10 minutes to download 7.6 GB with the Wi-Fi.

I spent the past 2 days trying all kind of troubleshooting I found online but none seem to solve my problem. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please edit your question to add RAM and more specs in general. Catalina should work on that system, but if you don’t have enough RAM that might be an issue. I would also more generally recommend downloading [Onyx](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html) and use it to do a deep clean of all of your system caches.

Comment: @JakeGould, thank you for suggesting **Onyx**, I will tried it out.